# what is krull dimension of Z[x]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I claim that the Krull dimension of $Z[x]$ is $2$. 
I can produce a chain of length 2 as $(0)\subset (p)\subset (p,x)$ but how do I rigorously prove that there is no chain of length 3.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to find the maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: Closing as an abstract duplicate as per the above suggestion.